# Not Able to Output Check States by Comparing Two Arrays

Tags: php

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to generate an output like this

[image]

by comparing two arrays (one associated `$items` and one regular `$selected`). Technically what I want to do is to check if the keys of `$items`  exist in `$selected` make a `checked` checkbox other than an empty checkbox

```
<?php
$items =[ [2] => 'Full', [4] => 'No', [3] => 'Semi'];
$selected = [ 2, 3];

$keys = array_keys($items);
foreach($keys as $key ){
    if (in_array($key, $selected)) {
    echo '<input id="checkBox" value="'.$key.'" type="checkbox" checked>';
}
    else{
         echo '<input id="checkBox" value="'.$key.'" type="checkbox">';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to this:

```
$items = ['2' => 'Full', '4' => 'No', '3' => 'Semi'];
$selected = [2, 3];

$keys = array_keys($items);
foreach($keys as $key ){
    if (in_array($key, $selected)) {
         echo '<input id="checkBox" value="'.$key.'" type="checkbox" checked>';
    }
    else{
         echo '<input id="checkBox" value="'.$key.'" type="checkbox">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for code I am getting the check boxes as they are but nothing for their label( the values)

Comment: Well, that's an another issue altogether which you haven't specified in your original question.